# TypeError When trying to insert byte data to MySQL query

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python

I'm currently using Python 3 and MySQLdb to communicate with a SQL server and I cannot insert byte data into a SQL query.
Here's the query:

```
exec = "select uuid from table where uuid=%s;"
```

Then I create a UUID to search for:

```
uuid = uuid.uuid4().bytes
```

And then I send it to the query through MySQLdb's `.execute()` function:

```
cursor.execute(exec, uuid)
```

But I get an error saying:

```
.../python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 210, in execute
query = query % args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here, how am I supposed to insert byte data into a MySQL query?

Comment: most questions I see like this the answer is to use a single element tuple like `cursor.execute(exec, (uuid,))` so that is worth a try.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Tried that and got the same error.

Comment: Ok then I don't know, sorry.

Comment: I was creating a tuple with parenthesis '(' and not square brackets '[', using square brackets resolved the problem, this can be marked as duplicate.
I'm sorry I could not find that question.